# Update Database after years of utilisation

Tags: c#, sql

**EDIT 1: story example at the end**

---

Years ago, we created tables in order to count how many products there were in our boxes.
There are two simple tables:

```
product (
    code VARCHAR(16) PK,
    length INT,
    width INT,
    height INT
)

box (
    pkid INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    barcode varchar(18),
    product_code VARCHAR(16) FK,
    quantity INT
)
```

And there two associated class:

```
public struct Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Heigth { get; set; }
}

public struct Box
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

---

After years, we need to put multiple different products in the same box, so we now need this:

```
product (
    code VARCHAR(16) PK,
    length INT,
    width INT,
    height INT
)

-- box changed
box (
    pkid INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    barcode varchar(18)
)

-- stock created
stock (
    box_pkid INT M-PK FK,
    product_code VARCHAR(16) M-PK FK,
    quantity INT
)
```

and this:

```
public struct Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Heigth { get; set; }
}

public struct Box
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Product, int> Content { get; set; } // <-- this changed
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

---

But after years, we have lot of code, maybe duplicates in some dark places, left by leaving collaborators. I am a trainee, so I ask for my future experiences, in order to avoid this later.

**What could be a solution to update our schema and keep data-integrity safe ? Even with millions of rows in DB ?**

---

**Example:**
In 2014, we needed to store 10 *Romeo and Juliet* books in one box. If we had some *Hamlet* books, then we put them in another box. All 10 *Romeo and Juliet* books were the 'same' product (same cover, same content, same reference).

Today, we want to store, let's say, different *Shakespear* books in the same box. Or maybe different *Love* books. Or even *Romeo and Juliet* books AND figurines? So different products together: we should change the `box table` and `Box class`, shouldn't we?

Comment: What, specifically, are you worried about? "Keep data integrity safe" is a very broad topic...

Comment: You say you are a trainee. This task is potentially risky, in terms of losing data, extended system downtime, wrong accounting, and many others. Someone with more experience should plan and be responsible for this. Take it to the Software Architect. He/She should be responsible for any decision here; that's why he/she makes the big bucks and you don't.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Can you show full story? `Box` has 1 `ID` and 1 `barcode`, which means same barcode could appear many times. is it a mistake? if yes, why do you need the table to store a column only, you can have a `index` to do same work in the column from `Box` . so you don't have to change schema at all

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't ask to change something, I ask because I would like to know for later. I will try to update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @penleychan: As the new requirement to store different products in the same box is not provided in the current implementation then that implementation is effectively broken & needs fixing. Or are you suggesting that storing only 1 product per box has worked for all these years - so don't change what you are doing.

Comment: The solution "don't change anything" is not the one I hope to read. I'm asking this in prevision that someday I **have to** make the modification, whatever the reason.

Comment: Resuming work on a legacy system without ending the world is commonplace for a developer. I'm surprised to see so many people telling the OP to bury their head in the sand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many challenges; I'd split them into two high-level groups.

Firstly, how do you change your application at the code level, and secondly, how do you migrate your data from the old schema to the new one.

### How do you change your code?

The first question is: can you be 100% certain that the classes you list are the only ways the data is accessed and modified? Are there any triggers, stored procedures, batch jobs, or other applications? I'm not aware of any way of finding this out other than by trawling through both the database schema artifacts, and the code base.

Within your "own" application, you have a choice. It's usually better to extend than modify your interface. In practical terms, that means that instead of changing the public `Product Product { get; set; }` signature to handle a dictionary, you keep it around, and add `public Dictionary<Product, int> Content { get; set; }` - if you can guarantee that the old method still works. This would mean limited re-writing all the dependencies of your class - you only have to worry about clients that need to understand that there could be more than 1 product in a box.

This allows you to follow a "lots of small changes, but the existing code continues to work" model; you can manage this via feature toggles etc. It's much lower risk - so the lesson here is "design your solution to [be open to extension, but closed to change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)".

In this case, it doesn't seem possible - the "set" method may be okay (you can default that to a "one product in a box" solution), but the "get" method would have no graceful way of handling the case where you have more than 1 product in a box. If that's true, you change the class, and look for all the instances where your code won't compile, and follow the chain of dependencies.

For instance, in a typical MVC framework, in this case you'd be changing the model; this should cause the controller to report a compile error. In resolving that error, you almost certainly modify the signature of the controller methods. This in turn should break the view. So you follow that chain; doing this means your schema change becomes a "big bang, all-or-nothing" release. This typically is stressful for all involved...

### How do you release your change?

This depends hugely on which of the two options you've chosen. @gburton's answer covers the database steps; these are necessary in both code options.

The second challenge is releasing new versions of your software; if it's a desktop client, for instance, you must make sure all clients are updated at the same time as your database change. This is (usually) horrible. If it's a web application, it's usually a little easier - fewer client machines to worry about.

Comment: If I well understand you, your suggestion in the applicative-side is to have something like this?  
`Box { public IContent Content { get; set; } }` ;  
`ProductQuantityPair : IContent { ... }` ;  
`ProductQuantityPairCollection : IContent { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Safely updating a legacy system is a classic problem. I'm guessing from your post that there isn't a nice safe dev copy of the DB, or at least one that is up to date, or you would already have a process to apply here.

I've written this in a system agnostic way even though you're obviously using MS SQL Server.

The key is to use caution, and ensure you are never 100% stuck if something goes wrong.

1. back up the old DB. **Ensure you know how to do this without breaking anything.**
2. Restore that backup into a new location.
3. figure out a test plan (this can be the longest part of the job)
4. make the changes to the new copy of the DB (don't touch the live one)
5. run through your test plan to ensure nothing has been broken.

If step 5 showed some errors, you just have to work through them. Once this is done, you have the scary part. The backup restore drill is critical here.

6. take backup of live database (your previous backup is probably out of date. you want as fresh a backup as possible to reduce data loss)
7. **run a backup restore drill to make 100% sure you can recover**
8. apply the changes to the live database
9. re-run your tests

Recovering a database down to the individual transaction is possible with many database engines. Consider using that process for step 6 if possible. How to achieve this would be a seperate question.